# modeling a multi-phase mixture of mediums in Modelica

Tags: simulation, modelica

Is there a systematic way of defining a water medium with minimal complexity (fixed heat capacity, fixed latent heats, fixed vapor pressure curves) that can be used to capture a *three-phase* pseudo-equilibrium dynamics in Modelica?

My ultimate usage scenario involves modeling simple air in the mixture as well and I am fairly confident in using air and liquid water together and have used a simple non-medium approach to deal with liquid and vapor but not through the medium models and suspect that I could capture the basic physics involved.